# In XSLT 2.0 I would like to get the unique nodes based on element value

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to get distinct nodes based on an element value.

My XML is like this:

```
<Body>
    <DR>
        <Id>2300129895</Id>
        <x>xx</x>
        <y>yy</y>
        <z>zz</z>
        <DR-Item>
            <q>qqq1</q>
            <w>www1</w>
            <e>eee1</e>
            <Container>Z015</Container>
            <r>rr_0</r>
            <t>tt_0</t>             
        </DR-Item>
        <DR-Item>
            <q>qqq2</q>
            <w>www1</w>
            <e>eee2</e>
            <Container>Z015</Container>
            <r>rr_0</r>
            <t>tt_0</t>             
        </DR-Item>
        <DR-Item>
            <q>qqq3</q>
            <w>www1</w>
            <e>eee1</e>
            <Container>Z016</Container>
            <r>rr_1</r>
            <t>tt_1</t>             
        </DR-Item>
    </DR>
</Body>
```

I need to call template only for `DR-items` with distinct `Container` values.

So I want to get output like this:

```
<GM>
    <Container>Z015</Container>
    <r>rr_0</r>
    <t>tt_0</t>
</GM>
<GM>
    <Container>Z016</Container>
    <r>rr_1</r>
    <t>tt_1</t>
</GM>
```

Any advice how I can do it?

Comment: *trying to get distinct nodes based on attributes.* Your sample XML has no attributes.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

XSLT 2.0 and later versions have a direct support for grouping.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Body>
    <DR>
        <Id>2300129895</Id>
        <x>xx</x>
        <y>yy</y>
        <z>zz</z>
        <DR-Item>
            <q>qqq1</q>
            <w>www1</w>
            <e>eee1</e>
            <Container>Z015</Container>
            <r>rr_0</r>
            <t>tt_0</t>
        </DR-Item>
        <DR-Item>
            <q>qqq2</q>
            <w>www1</w>
            <e>eee2</e>
            <Container>Z015</Container>
            <r>rr_0</r>
            <t>tt_0</t>
        </DR-Item>
        <DR-Item>
            <q>qqq3</q>
            <w>www1</w>
            <e>eee1</e>
            <Container>Z016</Container>
            <r>rr_1</r>
            <t>tt_1</t>
        </DR-Item>
    </DR>
</Body>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Body">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="DR/DR-Item"
                                group-by="Container">
                <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"
                          order="ascending"/>
                <GM>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Container"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="r"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="t"/>
                </GM>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<Body>
  <GM>
    <Container>Z015</Container>
    <r>rr_0</r>
    <t>tt_0</t>
  </GM>
  <GM>
    <Container>Z016</Container>
    <r>rr_1</r>
    <t>tt_1</t>
  </GM>
</Body>
```